# Python / Pygame grid design fails for append "index out of range"

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to create a grid starting at row 2, column 13. The grid will end at row 12, column 25.
However I keep getting a "list index out of range" error on the append(0)line.
Obviously I am not understanding how the append works.

```py
grid = []
for row in range(2,12):
    # Add an empty array that will hold each cell
    # in this row
    grid.append([])
    for column in range(13,25):
        grid[row].append(0)  # Append a cell
```

Comment: Programming languages count from zero, not one.

Comment: you are right but the subtraction of the row was where I was not understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The indices of lists always start at 0. `range(2, 12)` creates the numbers from 2 to 12. However the indices of the list `grid` still start at 0. You need to subtract 2 from `row`:

<s>`grid[row].append(0)  # Append a cell`</s>

```py
grid[row-2].append(0)  # Append a cell
```

---

Get the index of the next row with `len(grid)`, before appending a new row:

```py
grid = []
for row in range(2, 12):
    
    index_of_next_row = len(grid)
    grid.append([])
    
    for column in range(13, 25):
        grid[index_of_next_row].append(0)
```

Alternatively, you can create a roe and append it to the grid when the row is finished:

```py
grid = []
for row in range(2, 12):
    
    new_row = []
    
    for column in range(13, 25):
        new_row.append(0)

    grid.append(new_row)
```

Or even shorter:

```py
grid = [[0 for cell in range(13, 25)] for row in range(2, 12)]
```

Comment: I get the 0 start point, I failed to get that I need to return row back to zero for the append...thank you!